# Calculate mean for a each object of SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, function

I have a list with several SpatialPointsDataFrame objects, and each object has certain slots. How can I calculate the mean value of a certain slot for every object in the list, and then save that object (that was found to have the minimum mean value on that certain slot) to another object separately? I work with R.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lapply to return the mean(s) for a specific column present in all of your sp @data slots.

Create a list object with 2 sp point objects

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y

sp.list <- list()
  sp.list[[1]] <- meuse[1:78,]
  sp.list[[2]] <- meuse[79:155,]
```

Now we can return the mean(s) for the cadmium column in the @data slot. The x object used in the function represents the sp object.

```
lapply(sp.list, FUN=function(x) { mean(x@data$cadmium) } )
```

To return the position of the list element with the minimum mean you can unlist the results of lapply and the use which.min to return the position of the minimum mean.

```
which.min(unlist(lapply(sp.list, FUN=function(x) { mean(x@data$cadmium) } )))
```

To expand this to subset the minimum mean to a new sp object.

```
min.sp <- sp.list[[which.min(unlist(lapply(sp.list, FUN=function(x) { mean(x@data$cadmium) } )))]]
```